# Multiple columns in QueryDSL

Tags: java, database, querydsl

I'm trying to get a list of multiple columns from my table using QueryDSL, and automatically fill my DB object, like this example in an older manual:

```
List<CatDTO> catDTOs = query.from(cat)
    .list(EConstructor.create(CatDTO.class, cat.id, cat.name));
```

The problem is that it looks like the EConstructor class was removed in version 2.2.0, and all the examples I find now are like this:

```
List<Object[]> rows = query.from(cat)
    .list(cat.id, cat.name);
```

Which forces me to manually cast all the objects into my CatDTO class.

Is there any alternative to this? Any EConstructor alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EConstructor has been replaced with ConstructorExpression in Querydsl 2.0. So your example would become

```
List<CatDTO> catDTOs = query.from(cat)
    .list(ConstructorExpression.create(CatDTO.class, cat.id, cat.name));
```

You can also annotate the CatDTO constructor and query like this

```
List<CatDTO> catDTOs = query.from(cat)
    .list(new QCatDTO(cat.id, cat.name));
```

Alternatively you can use the QTuple projection which provides a more generic access option

```
List<Tuple> rows = query.from(cat)
    .list(new QTuple(cat.id, cat.name));
```

The actual values can be accessed via their path like this

```
tuple.get(cat.id)
```

and

```
tuple.get(cat.name)
```

Tuple projection will probably be used in Querydsl 3.0 for multiple columns projections instead of Object arrays.

Comment: So in either case (List<Object[]> or List<Tuple>) I need to manually assign each return object value to my CatDTO class?

Comment: EConstructor is ConstructorExpression since 2.0, alternatively you can annotate the constructor of CatDTO with @QueryProjection and use new QCatDTO(...

Comment: @balizeiro, do you need any other info?

Comment: No, everything is ok. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

using queryDSL 4 and Java 8 stream:

```
List<CatDTO> cats = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager)
        .select(cat.id, cat.name)
        .from(cat)
        .fetch()
        .stream()
        .map(c -> new CatDTO(c.get(cat.id), c.get(cat.name)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the class `Projections`. It will construct the object using the fields you pass as parameters, like the `EConstructor`. Example:

```
List<CatDTO> catDTOs = query.from(cat)
    .list(Projections.bean(CatDTO.class, cat.id, cat.name));
```

Reference: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.5/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/Projections.html